# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod Timeout

Tags: powershell

I check some many Services (roundabout 15) if there are available via the PowerShell command. If the service are available the script running time is well but if some service not available the script running time isn't well! So how can determine that the `Invoke-RestMethod` have a specific time for request/response? I know there is a Parameter `-TimeoutSec`.
For example if I get no response after 4 Seconds timeout the request and throw an error!

```
Invoke-RestMethod $uri -TimeoutSec
```

Maybe I have misunderstood the Parameter `-TimeoutSec`?

Comment: if you want the timeout to be infinite, then leave at the default of `0`. any other setting will apparently give an error if the timeout is exceeded. that is how i interpret the output of this ... `Get-Help Invoke-RestMethod -Parameter TimeoutSec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the help:

```
> get-help Invoke-RestMethod -Parameter Timeoutsec

-TimeoutSec <Int32>
    Specifies how long the request can be pending before it times out. Enter a value in seconds. The default value, 0, specifies an indefinite time-out.
```

So the parameter needs an integer to say how long to the timeout should be.

```
Invoke-RestMethod $uri -TimeoutSec 4
```

Please note the caveat that is also in the help:

```
A Domain Name System (DNS) query can take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires resolution, and you set TimeoutSec to a value greater than zero, but less than 15 seconds, it can take 15 
seconds or more before a WebException is thrown, and your request times out.
```